# XSLT: remove empty elements under specific node

Tags: xslt

input

```
 <person>
    <address>
       <city>NY</city>
       <state></state>
       <country>US</country>
    </address>
    <other>
       <gender></gender>
       <age>22</age>
       <weight/>
    </other>
 </person>
```

i only want to remove empty elements from the 'other' node, also the tags under 'other' are not fixed.

output

```
<person>
    <address>
       <city>NY</city>
       <state></state>
       <country>US</country>
    </address>
    <other>
       <age>22</age>
    </other>
 </person>
```

I'm new to xslt so pls help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="other/*[not(node())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<person>
    <address>
        <city>NY</city>
        <state></state>
        <country>US</country>
    </address>
    <other>
        <gender></gender>
        <age>22</age>
        <weight/>
    </other>
</person>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<person>
   <address>
      <city>NY</city>
      <state/>
      <country>US</country>
   </address>
   <other>
      <age>22</age>
   </other>
</person>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies "as-is" every matched node, for which it is selected for execution.
2. The only template that overrides the identity templates matches any element that is a child of `other` and has no children nodes (is empty). As this template has no body, this effectively "deletes" the matched element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="person">
        <person>
            <xsl:copy-of select="address"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="other"/>
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="other">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <xsl:if test=".!=''">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```